# Python, Mysql : localhost connection failed

Tags: python, mysql, connection

I want to access my local Mysql database, I am using

```
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',
         password='',
         host='127.0.0.1')
```

But I have the following error :

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied
> for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing MySQL from Python 3: Access denied for user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852163/accessing-mysql-from-python-3-access-denied-for-user)

Comment: Use non-empty password; It works.

Comment: I have tried a space for the password and I have the same problem @Sangharsh

Comment: thank you @vishes_shell, I have seen this post, it didn't help.

Comment: `conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',  password='root');` works. (Assuming root password is `root`)

Comment: thank you  @Sangharsh , it worked !! :)

Comment: In given error, it is mentioned `(using password: NO)`. MySQL by default is not accessible to root without password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use non-empty password. MySQL by default is not accessible to root used without password.

Given error says:

> (using password: NO)

Use with password:

```
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',
         password='root',
         host='127.0.0.1')
```