# Access denied with Python to remote mysql connection. (ssh via Pycharm data source)

Tags: python, mysql, ssh, pycharm

I manage to establish a connection to a remote mysql server with pycharm's database feature.

```
1. View > Tool Windows > Databases
2. Click on +
3. Navigate to SSH/SSL
4. Insert ssh details
5. Test connection
```

The test connection works with the below message:

```
DBMS: MySQL (ver. 8.0.21) Case sensitivity: plain=exact, delimited=exact Driver: MySQL Connector/J (ver. mysql-connector-java-8.0.21 (Revision: 33f65445a1bcc544eb0120491926484da168f199), JDBC4.2) Ping: 210 ms SSL: yes
```

Now that I am connected to the mysql database via ssh I should be able to connect and run queries via a python script like so:

```
config = {
        'user': 'jsadmin',
        'password': 'password',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'database': 'mmdb',
        'port': 3306,
        'raise_on_warnings': True,
    }
conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
```

The above is giving me an error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jsadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Why is there this error If I can run queries with the above credentials from pycharm's database console?

### Edit

even having the same version of the `mysql-connector-python` to mysql server still produced the same issue

The question is once I shh from pycharm's data source properties window, is the server `ip` now `localhost` from python code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing MySQL from Python 3: Access denied for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852163/accessing-mysql-from-python-3-access-denied-for-user)

Comment: still had same error

Comment: as far as I know, the fact you registered a datasource in pycharm has nothing to do with the python code you may write, it only allows you to interact with the db trough pycharm UI