# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user (using password: YES). SSL is required

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I get this error while trying to run a python3 script to extract from MariaDB.

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user 'my_username' (using password: YES). SSL is required
```

With **SSL is required** at the end

Script line error:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=username, password=password,
                                      host=site[2], database=site[1])
```

I went to mysql.connector doc:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html
and tried to use the `ssl_verify_identity=True` argument but it doesn't work, it says the arg is not supported. (I'm guessing I don't know how to use it or where?)

I use Keyring for the username and password.
I have openSSL installed, the DB I'm trying to connect to requires SSL

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852163/accessing-mysql-from-python-3-access-denied-for-user? It is a bit different, this error msg says "SSL is required" (btw SSL stands for secure sockets layer, a predecessor of TLS. It is still used, though deprecated, primarily for access to something over LAN/HTTPS w/ encryption). Check your password, port number, and make sure your authorisation details are correct (password, username).