# connecting with python to a mysql database that is on an ubuntu server (located on a virtual machine on the same computer)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database, ubuntu, vmware-workstation

How can I connect with python to a mysql database that is on an ubuntu server (located on a VMware Workstation on the same computer)? My operating system is Windows.

import pymysql
from tkinter import messagebox

conn = pymysql.connect(host=".....", user="......", password="......", database="........", port=...)

cursor = conn.cursor()
get_students = "select * from students"

try:
cursor.execute(get_students)
conn.commit()
for i in cursor:
print(i[1])
except:
messagebox.showinfo("Failed to fetch files from database")

This code gives me an error: "Access denied for the user....."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852163/accessing-mysql-from-python-3-access-denied-for-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852163/accessing-mysql-from-python-3-access-denied-for-user)